# Kartograph - "projection not named"

Tags: python, coordinate-system

The [Kartograph](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/#using-kartograph-py) package looks very promising, so I have been trying play around with it.  As it turns out, I have been able to get the most basic map to work (the ["world.json" example](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/install-ubuntu.html#test-installation)), but I could not get any of the shapefiles I actually needed to work. (I am primarily concerned with Washington DC, at least professionally.)  They all throw the same exception:

```
from kartograph import Kartograph
K = Kartograph()

nbhds={"layers": [{"id":"mylayer",
                   "src": "/home/choct155/ora_public/dc_shp/CompPlanPlanningAreas.shp"
                   }],
       "proj":{"id":"mercator"
               }
       }

K.generate(nbhds, outfile='nbhds.svg')
```

---

```
RuntimeError: projection not named
```

I tried to follow the world example exactly (changing only the path of the shapefile) and played around with various configurations I saw others use.  Further, as you can see above, I also tried explicitly setting the projection.  Searching this error returns exactly one [hit](https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/issues/90), identifying the LCC projection as the culprit.  All DC shapefiles use the NAD83 datum and Lambert Conformal Conic projection.  Even if I build up from Census shapefiles, as soon as I interact with a DC shapefile (when, for example, mapping blocks to DC geographies) this issue crops up.

I have been able to circumvent this by converting the base file to a different projection, but LCC is really the best projection for my area (and the addition to the workflow is a bit annoying).  Does anyone know of a way around this?

Also, I have generally found less resources than I would expect for some pretty common spatial operations.  In the interest of providing another resource for those learning to deal with spatial data in Python, here is a [rough workflow](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/choct155/MiscProj/blob/master/ProjectionConvert.ipynb) that may be of some use for *converting shapefiles from one projection to another.*

Comment: Are you sure that `mercator` is a valid projection name for the tool? The documentation is not very detailed in that aspect.

Comment: Thanks for checking in Andre.  `mercator` is legit projection call.  The docs could certainly use more detail, but the available calls can be found in the [source](https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/blob/master/kartograph/proj/__init__.py).  That being said, I did try other projections as well.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the author about it. Without proper documentation the tool is not very useful.

Comment: This is a good idea.  As it turns out, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/issues/90) on the Github site.  It was opened 5 months ago, so I bumped it again.